# Request times out to Apache on Ubuntu Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox, apache2

I'm new to this so probably missing something obvious. I am running Ubuntu Server on Virtual Box. I have installed Apache on the server. I now want to be able to access it from the browser. My guest IP is: 10.0.2.15. When I visit it in my browser the request times out.

When I am logged in to the Ubuntu server and run `wget 10.0.2.15`, it saves the Apache default `index.html` to my working directory.

I have disabled UFW.

Comment: How is networking configured in virtualbox?

Comment: @vidarlo The only change I've made to the default settings is to set up port forwarding for SSH.

Comment: What is the actual settings? Not what you have changed from the default, but the *actual* settings in use. Is it bridged or NAT? Is SSH working?

Comment: NAT. SSH is working.

Comment: Have you set up port forwarding for HTTP as well?

Comment: I hadn't, no. But now I have, and it works. Thanks!